# C# Flexible/Dynamic USING for publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, using

I have the following lines of code:

```
using XXX.PAD.PaidServices;
using YYY= XXX.PAD.PaidServices.Judet;
//// uncomment below for the test version and comment 2 lines above
//using XXX.PAD.PaidServices_Test;
//using YYY= XXX.PAD.PaidServices_Test.Judet;
```

In order for me to publish the solution I have to make this change in every .cs file that holds these usings.

Is there any way to get rid of this annoyng task on every publish type change ?
Eventually something stored in web.config
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at dependency inversion instead?

Comment: I've found an article here: http://www.aspiringcraftsman.com/tag/dependency-inversion-principle/     

But could you please give me some details or an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pre-processing directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691094%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) and a [conditional compilation symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

```
#if TEST
using XXX.PAD.PaidServices_Test;
using YYY= XXX.PAD.PaidServices_Test.Judet;
#else
using XXX.PAD.PaidServices;
using YYY= XXX.PAD.PaidServices.Judet;
#endif
```

Hope that helps!